# SQL query count elements in other table

Tags: sql, sql-server, relational-database

I have two SQL tables, Projects and Milestones:

Projects PK -> ProID

Milestones combined PK -> ProID and MstNo

For some reason I cannot use ProID as a foreign key to link those two tables together (FOREIGN KEY constraint). However, I need to write a query which would show me details of all of the Projects table records, together with a number of milestones for each project. Can I use inner join to achieve that somehow? I'm not good with writing SQL queries.

Comment: What kind of error / problem did you encounter when you tried to set up your foreign key constraint?

Comment: Answer to your question `Can I use inner join to achieve that somehow?` is `YES`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one -

```
SELECT 
       P.*
     , cnt = ISNULL(M.cnt, 0)
FROM dbo.Projects P
LEFT JOIN (
     SELECT ProID, cnt = COUNT(1) 
     FROM dbo.Milestones
     GROUP BY ProID
) M ON M.ProID = P.ProID
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. `inner join` match data from one table with another on declared condition.

`select * from Projects inner join Milestones on Projects.ProId = Milestones.ProID`.

This query will read all data from `Projects` table and match to it data from `Milestones`.

In the result you will have the entities that have ProId in both tables.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT P.ProID ,
       COUNT(M.*)
FROM   Projects P
       LEFT JOIN Milestones M
           ON M.ProID = P.ProID
GROUP BY P.ProID
```

Answer (score 0):

If I got the tables structure you should write something like

```
SELECT
  ProID,
  count(*) as MstNo
FROM projects
LEFT JOIN milestones ON projects.ProID=milestones.ProID
GROUP BY ProID
```

even better

```
SELECT
  ProID,
  sum(
    CASE WHEN milestones.ProID is null THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
  ) as MstNo
FROM projects
LEFT JOIN milestones ON projects.ProID=milestones.ProID
GROUP BY ProID
```

In this way you will have a count of 0 for the projects without milestones yet